# Do filters work on an online report in Power BI?

Tags: filter, powerbi, publish

Please, I created this report and published it on the [web](https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiZjExZjc0N2MtMjhiYS00MTJlLTg0MzQtZjYyMTBmYjRhNmI2IiwidCI6Ijc4YjM3ZDM1LWY0NTctNGYyNy04NmY0LTQ2MTI5MzQ5MjRhZSJ9&pageName=ReportSection)

But it is interesting that the filters that I enabled in three columns do not appear - they only work on my computer, in the desktop version. Does Publishing to the Power BI Web not allow you to include filters?

Comment: Can you show what the filters look like in the desktop version?

Comment: Did you got any solution around this? I'm also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Filters should work the same with Publish to Web.

One thing you need to keep in mind is that there can be a significant lag between publishing the file and when the public link is updated.

From [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-publish-to-web):

> ## How it works (technical details)
>
> When you create an embed code using **Publish to web**, the report is made visible to Internet users. It's publicly available, so you can expect viewers to easily share the report through social media in the future. Users view the report either by opening the direct public URL or viewing it embedded in a web page or blog. As they do, Power BI caches the report definition and the results of the queries required to view the report. This caching ensures that thousands of concurrent users can view the report without impacting performance.
>
> The data is cached for one hour from the time it is retrieved. If you update the report definition (for example, if you change its View mode) or refresh the report data, it can take some time before changes are reflected in the version of the report that your users view. When a data refresh occurs for an import data model, the service clears the cached data and retrieves new data. In most cases, the data is updated nearly simultaneous with the import of the data. However, for reports with many distinct queries, it may take some time to update. Since each element and data value is cached independently, when a data update occurs, a user may see a mix of current and previous values. Therefore, we recommend staging your work ahead of time, and creating the **Publish to web** embed code only when you're satisfied with the settings. If your data will refresh, minimize the number of refreshes and perform the refreshes at off hours. We don’t recommend using Publish to web for data that needs to refresh frequently.

Comment: Thanks @AlexisOlson but I created it about 3 days ago. And the filter has not yet appeared

Comment: Did you republish after applying the filters? (Just trying to rule things out.)

Comment: Yes, several times

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the Filtering enabled in the 'Options and settings' section of the Desktop PBI before publishing.
[Screenshot Attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09uAa.png)